# PHP - Scan dir for folders and txt

Tags: php

I am dynamically building an accordion menu. Accordion will get the header information from folder names and contents from .txt files associated to folder names. They are relatives in terms of directory.

```
<div class="accordion">
<?php if($_GET['cat']!='') {

$handleCat = 'tv/'.$_GET['cat'];
$category = scandir($handleCat);
$i = 1;
        foreach ($category as &$value) {if ((!in_array($value,array(".","..","...")))){
        echo '<div class="header">'.$value.'</div><div class="content" id="ac'.$i.'">'.file_get_contents($value.".txt", false).'</div>';
$i+=1;}}}

 ?>
</div>
```

In my code there are two problems. First one is logic problem. I couldn't made up scan foldernames and file names seperately. Forexample program1.txt also becomes a headername. Second problem is method problem. I found file_get_contents() method but this doesn't extracts .txt file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distinguish files from folders using the function is_dir().

As of file_get_contents, it reads the file contents but does not echo it. Use :

```
echo '<div class="header">'.$value.'</div>'.$value.'<div class="content" id="ac'.$i.'">';
echo file_get_contents($value.".txt", false);
echo'</div>';
```

Comment: _file_get_contents_ needed directory seperator: **($handleCat . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value).".txt"**. That was the problem. _is_dir()_ also worked like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to list files in a directory. Where I commented `code` you can do whatever you want with that particular file. You can use `is_dir()` to distinguish from files and directories and then proceed accordingly.

```
<?php
    if ($dir = opendir('.')) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                echo "$file\n";
                //code
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
   }
?>
```

Read the contents of a file using the following code.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
```